# Magento 2: How to show Prices for OUT of stock products

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock, product-prices

I'm pretty new to Magento in general and just started working with Magento 2.

Here is my question - How to show prices for all out of stock products?

There is this topic: [Magento 2 : How To Show Price of "out of stock" Products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156922/magento-2-how-to-show-price-of-out-of-stock-products)

And apparently it works, but half of the instructions don't make sense to me.
After creating custom module, what should I do with it? Should I change anything else anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable your module?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure how to do it :)

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command to activate your module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 : How To Show Price of "out of stock" Products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156922/magento-2-how-to-show-price-of-out-of-stock-products)

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create directory /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/. in [Magento\Directory\Helper\Data\Proxy] in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Directo...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Directo...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Directo...') #3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Objec

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create your custom module using below code

Let say module name **Custom_Outofstock**

So create folder in **app/code**

Create **registration.php** file at **app/code/Custom/Outofstock/registration.php**

Add below code to it:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_Outofstock',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create **module.xml** at **app/code/Custom/Outofstock/etc/module.xml**

Add below code to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Outofstock" setup_version="2.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Now create file suggested in [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156922/magento-2-how-to-show-price-of-out-of-stock-products)
answer given By Sohel Rana as below

Create di.xml at **app/code/Custom/Outofstock/etc/di.xml**

Add below code to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Custom\Outofstock\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

Create Price render file **FinalPriceBox.php** at **app/code/Custom/Outofstock/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php**

Add below code to it:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Outofstock\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $result = parent::_toHtml();

        if(!$result) {
            $result = BasePriceBox::_toHtml();
            try {
                /** @var MsrpPrice $msrpPriceType */
                $msrpPriceType = $this->getSaleableItem()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('msrp_price');
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
                return $this->wrapResult($result);
            }

            //Renders MSRP in case it is enabled
            $product = $this->getSaleableItem();
            if ($msrpPriceType->canApplyMsrp($product) && $msrpPriceType->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product)) {
                /** @var BasePriceBox $msrpBlock */
                $msrpBlock = $this->rendererPool->createPriceRender(
                    MsrpPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                    $this->getSaleableItem(),
                    [
                        'real_price_html' => $result,
                        'zone' => $this->getZone(),
                    ]
                );
                $result = $msrpBlock->toHtml();
            }

            return $this->wrapResult($result);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now run below command to enable module:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Flush cache using below command:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
However, after doing this, all the css was overwritten with default css which came with theme. And products are not displaying whatsoever, instead I get this message: "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email". 

In exception log i have this message: 
"[2017-02-13 17:11:58] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'The element 'product.info.options' already has a child with alias 'default'' in /home/uspatriot/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611"

Any ideas what happened?

Comment: Actually, after enabling developer mode, then disabling it, and then enabling production mode, this is the error I get now: 
"Fatal error: Class 'Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox' not found in /home/uspatriot/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93"

Comment: So, I figured there was a mistake in di.xml.
After changing type from "Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" to "Custom\Outofstock\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox", and re-enabling production mode, it all works now!

Comment: Yes that is error I forgot to modify it. I have updated code thanks for acknowledge

Comment: Is there any modification to show "as low as" price only of "in stock" products on configurable product? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181053/lowest-price-of-configurable-product-as-low-as