# Show price for out of stock configurable products

Tags: magento2.2, out-of-stock

How to show price of configurable product which is out of stock in magento2.2? Currently when child product's are out of stock then configurable product won't show price in magento 2.2.

Please help!

Comment: did you try [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156922/magento-2-how-to-show-price-of-out-of-stock-products) ?

Comment: Thanks Adrian for quick reply, i already tried in new magento 2.2 fresh instance, but still has same issue

Comment: Try This : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197516/59400

Comment: This is what for price shown as 0.00. Anyway it is also tried and but same issues. i can send you module which i have developed from above two links.

Comment: Did someone found the solution? I am also getting the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143422)

Comment: did someone maybe found a solution for this issue, i have a 2.3.5 install but out of stock configurable products shows as low ass 0€ - but i need to have the lowest price of the configurable product . anyone has an idea? thanks