# How to display price for out of stock products in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, configurable-product, out-of-stock, manage-stock

How to display the price for out of stock product (configurable type) in magento2.

I also refer to these links: [Magento2: show price for out of stock configurable products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161079/magento2-show-price-for-out-of-stock-configurable-products).

[Magento 2 : How To Show Price of "out of stock" Products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156922/magento-2-how-to-show-price-of-out-of-stock-products)

But not working

How to do that.

Thanks.