# Show price for out of stock products in recently viewed products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In recently viewed products, the price is not showing for **Out of Stock** products.

I have to show Out Of Stock products as client requirement.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question. So you want the price to display for out of stock products?

Comment: @BareFeet Yes, i have to render price for out of stock products.

Answer (score 2):

Best option would be creating your own custom module to add custom code. Call it `CustomModule_AddPriceToOutOfStock`

Now, create a directory in **app/code**
Add **registration.php** file at **app/code/CustomModule/AddPriceToOutOfStock/registration.php**

With following code:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'CustomModule_AddPriceToOutOfStock',
    __DIR__
);
```

You also need to create **module.xml** at **app/code/CustomModule/AddPriceToOutOfStock/etc/module.xml**

With following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CustomModule_AddPriceToOutOfStock" setup_version="2.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Now create **di.xml** at **app/code/Custom/Outofstock/etc/di.xml**

With below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="CustomModule\AddPriceToOutOfStock\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

Now, create Price render file **FinalPriceBox.php** at **app/code/CustomModule/AddPriceToOutOfStock /Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php**

With below code:

```
<?php
namespace CustomModule\AddPriceToOutOfStock\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $result = parent::_toHtml();

        if(!$result) {
            $result = BasePriceBox::_toHtml();
            try {
                /** @var MsrpPrice $msrpPriceType */
                $msrpPriceType = $this->getSaleableItem()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('msrp_price');
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
                return $this->wrapResult($result);
            }

            //Renders MSRP in case it is enabled
            $product = $this->getSaleableItem();
            if ($msrpPriceType->canApplyMsrp($product) && $msrpPriceType->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product)) {
                /** @var BasePriceBox $msrpBlock */
                $msrpBlock = $this->rendererPool->createPriceRender(
                    MsrpPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                    $this->getSaleableItem(),
                    [
                        'real_price_html' => $result,
                        'zone' => $this->getZone(),
                    ]
                );
                $result = $msrpBlock->toHtml();
            }

            return $this->wrapResult($result);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Enable the module using:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And flush the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[Magento 2 : How To Show Price of "out of stock" Products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156922/magento-2-how-to-show-price-of-out-of-stock-products)

Comment: I have tried this but still, it was not coming.

Comment: I just tired it myself, and it did work for me..

Comment: ok trying again

Comment: No need to down-vote tho haha :D But okey, I hope it works for you, I use this myself with no problems. Also, do you get any errors?

Comment: Also, what version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I have not downvoted bro.

Comment: I am using 2.2.5

Comment: I have used it again but its not coming

Comment: I am using 2.1.2 and this works. Hymmm you get any errors in logs?

Comment: No error regarding this in logs, the price is coming in list page but not in recently viewed products.

Comment: hymmm.... just looking at my recently viewed products and they they display the price either... I was looking at the catalog...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, however, I am now curious how it's done. Please let me know if you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's using KO js to generate the price box for recently viewed products, so you can following the steps below:
Add 2 files to your theme
**Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/price/regular_price.html**

```
<if args="getRegularPrice($row())">
    <span css="'old-price': hasSpecialPrice($row()), 'regular-price': !hasSpecialPrice($row())">
        <span class="price-container"
              css="getAdjustmentCssClasses($row())">
            <span if="label && hasSpecialPrice($row())"
                  class="price-label"
                  text="label"/>

            <span class="price-wrapper"
                  css="priceWrapperCssClasses"
                  attr="priceWrapperAttr"
                  data-price-amount=""
                  data-price-type=""
                  html="getRegularPrice($row())"/>

            <if args="!hasSpecialPrice($row())">
                <each args="data: getAdjustments(), as: '$adj'">
                    <render args="$adj.getBody()"/>
                </each>
            </if>
        </span>
    </span>
</if>
```

**Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/price/special_price.html**

```
<if args="hasSpecialPrice($row())">
    <span class="special-price">
        <span class="price-container"
              css="getAdjustmentCssClasses($row())">
            <span if="label"
                  class="price-label"
                  text="label"/>

            <span class="price-wrapper"
                  css="priceWrapperCssClasses"
                  attr="priceWrapperAttr"
                  data-price-amount=""
                  data-price-type="finalPrice"
                  html="getPrice($row())"/>

            <each args="data: getAdjustments(), as: '$adj'">
                <render args="$adj.getBody()"/>
            </each>
        </span>
    </span>
</if>
```